# Please add a new tag "Shortcuts"

Tags: feature-request, tags

I'm gonna leave this pretty short because its pretty self explanatory.  [Shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/shortcuts/welcome/ios) was recently released by Apple on iOS 12. I think we need a tag. I have enough rep to create the tag, but a tag for "Shortcut" already exists. Can we please create this tag?

Comment: Wanted to bring this up anyway, thanks for the question. The "shortcut" tag currently is used for keyboard shortcuts, having both "shortcut" *and* "shortcuts" will probably confuse people. Let me do some quick analysis on their use, will add a proposal below.

Comment: In the meantime, can you add your proposal for excerpt/description of [tag:siri-shortcuts]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Where are we coming from?

Currently we have

- [shortcut](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shortcut) with 557 tagged questions, described as

> Series of one or several keys that invoke some software/os action when triggered by the user
>
> A Shortcut is a series of one or several keys that invoke some software/os action when triggered by the user. Common known keyboard shortcuts in Mac OS X are for example <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> fie quitting an application, <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> for closing a window or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for copying some data and <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> for pasting the copied data.

- [keyboard-shortcuts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-shortcuts) as a synonym of [keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard)
- [keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard) with 3686 tagged questions, described as

> A physical device with buttons that allow characters to be entered
>
> The keyboard is a means of interacting with a device, whether it be using a combination of keys to execute an action (see [shortcuts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shortcuts)) or typing to produce sentences.

---

### Some thoughts

- [shortcut](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shortcut) seems mainly to be used to ask for keyboard shortcuts (also [shortcut](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shortcut) is often used together with [keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard)), [keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard) covers both hardware and software/shortcut topics though. So just merging [shortcut](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shortcut) into [keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard) will lead to a loss of granularity.
- Given the multiple meanings of the term "shortcut(s)" having a generic tag with that name will lead to confusion and wrong usage (as nobody seems to read tag descriptions anyway)

---

### Proposal

- Keep [keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard) as today
- Break synonym link between [keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard) and [keyboard-shortcuts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-shortcuts)
- Merge [shortcut](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shortcut) into [keyboard-shortcuts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-shortcuts) (and delete [shortcut](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shortcut) if possible)
- Create new [siri-shortcuts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/siri-shortcuts)
- Provide helpful excerpts/descriptions for all three

---

Any comments, remarks, feedback?

Comment: Great idea. And thanks for background.

Comment: I’ll propose a second way to leave all these alone and make a new tag for iOS-shortcuts or shortcut.app - I’ll see if I can find any stupyle guide references to see how Apple describes these functions or in KB documentation.

Answer (score 4):

My initial thoughts would be to leave the keyboard shortcuts alone and have [shortcuts.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shortcuts.app) or [ios-shortcuts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios-shortcuts) cover the workflow.app being renamed to shortcuts as an application you download from the iOS App Store. Since it intercepts intents from Apple and third party apps to become siri-shortcuts, the siri tag might work just fine for any voice command questions In conjunction with the app tag.

I think we might get better usage results with either **.app** or **iOS-** added to the word **shortcuts**.